# What is 1024 in "The length MUST NOT exceed 2^14 + 1024" in TLS?

Tags: tls

In RFC 5246,

Chapter 6.2.2:
Record Compression and Decompression: (page 21)

> The length (in bytes) of the following TLSCompressed.fragment. The
>   length MUST NOT exceed 2^14 + 1024.

Chapter 6.2.3:
Record Payload Protection: (page 21)

> The length (in bytes) of the following TLSCiphertext.fragment. The
>   length MUST NOT exceed 2^14 + 2048.

In this context, 2^14 means the length of `TLSPlaintext.fragment`. What does 1024 and 2048 mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These numbers don't “mean” anything, they're just numbers chosen to be sensible.

For compression, the reason is given just above:

> Compression must be lossless and may not increase the content length by more than 1024 bytes.

Since the content may be at most 2^14 bytes long, the compressed version of it may be at most 2^14 + 1024 bytes long. If a TLS endpoint receives a TLSCompressed fragment that is too large, it is allowed (and even expected) to terminate the connection, because the sender is sending it invalid data. This sort of limitation allows TLS endpoints to know the maximum amount of memory they will need to support a connection in the worst case.

For TLSCiphertext, a payload of at most 2^14 + 1024 bytes is encrypted. The result has some overhead (nonce, authentication tag, padding) that depends on the encryption method. This clause guarantees that no matter what the encryption method is, the overhead will never be more than 1024 bytes. (Actually the wording here does not guarantee this limit for the overhead when the payload is less than 2^14 bytes. There is an explicit guarantee in §6.2.3.3 for AEAD ciphers, but not for the other ciphers, which is probably an oversight.)