# Lots of TLSCiphertext length MUST NOT exceed 2^14 + 2048 in wireshark

Tags: tls, wireshark, heartbleed

We have small network with ~20 clients (Wifi and Lan). I captured a few seconds of our network traffic with wireshark and encountered a lot of `TLSCiphertext length MUST NOT exceed 2^14 + 2048`  errors in the expert analysis for different IPs. Below a screenshot of the filter `ssl.record.length.invalid`. The destination is always a client IP in our local network. Sources are various outside IPs.

[image]

I read the [RFC5246 specs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) and a bit about the Heartbleed bug. All  routers /firewalls in our network are patched for the OpenSSL bug. Furthermore, from time to time we also have an `invalid heartbeat payload length error` visible in Wireshark. I googled a bit around but I am unsure how severe is this error?

Here is a more detailed output of one of the `Encrypted Alert, Ignored Unknown Record` messages:

```
Secure Sockets Layer
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Encrypted Alert
        Content Type: Alert (21)
        Version: Unknown (0x9620)
        Length: 59447
            [Expert Info (Error/Protocol): TLSCiphertext length MUST NOT exceed 2^14 + 2048]
                [TLSCiphertext length MUST NOT exceed 2^14 + 2048]
                [Severity level: Error]
                [Group: Protocol]
        Alert Message: Encrypted Alert
```

Comment: Can you capture the TLS handshake and see if it makes sense? Which cipher suite is chosen? Is this really TLS traffic, or just packets that begin with 0x03 0x03?

Comment: Thanks, I will later have a look at this.

Comment: I now had a look at this. I recorded the handshake which looks fine for me.  As Cipher suite either ECDSA or RSA is used:

Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc02c)
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)

Actually how can I detect if this is real TLS traffic?

Comment: potentially useful? https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/200723/what-is-1024-in-the-length-must-not-exceed-214-1024-in-tls

Comment: If you remove the filter, are there normal looking flows? start TCP connection, TLS handshake, TLS data in one direction, then in another, like request + response, eventually closing connection? Or this traffic that only resembles TLS, and the TLS handshakes you found belong to different connections? You said dest is always in local network? Is there traffic in the other direction? What does it look like? Maybe this is a VPN or something that looks like TLS.

Comment: Actually yes, most of the traffic is looking normal.
The TLS alerts are present for different outside locations but above shown is only one connection. Also I see the alerts on different clients. The only thing I encountered is a lot of TCP re transmissions (5-10%).

I will have a look at this site for a better understanding of TLS: http://blog.fourthbit.com/2014/12/23/traffic-analysis-of-an-ssl-slash-tls-session/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a wrong interpretation of the data. What most likely happened is that some TCP segments got out of order or lost, confusing the TLS dissector in Wireshark. This seems to be supported by your observation of retransmitted packets.

Some applications also do not align the start of a TLS records with the begin of a TCP segment when a lot of data is being pushed, filling up a full TLS record.

When Wireshark loses track of the start of a TLS record, it will guess that the start of a TCP segment coincides with the start of a TLS record. Clearly that will not work if the previous case applies. If you right-click on the packet and use Follow Stream -> TCP stream, you'll most likely see some "Ignored Unknown Record".

Assuming you have have captured all packets, you can fix out-of-order TCP segments handling by enabling a TCP preference, see https://wiki.wireshark.org/TLS#Preference_Settings

As for the expert info on exceeding the record size, that was added to help catching implementation bugs where a too large record was sent. In your case it is bogus. See these commits:

- https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/commit/ff0371e898
- https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/commit/bb1450b017